# Truncating Data Passed to Form from MySql (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Below is a sample line of code from the HTML form that is created and the data is receives:

```
    Mission: <input readonly type='text' name='mission' value=".$mission.">
```

It works fine, but the data is truncated. For example, if the mission is "Mission Five", the "Five" gets cut off.

Comment: make a jsfiddle of it or post the offending code, the five isn't in this snippet

Comment: Tell us, what does your HTML source reveal? ;-)

Comment: ...which is just as good a "tool" as any ^

Answer (score 3):

Because you forgot quote your attributes. Your html will be

```
 <input [..snip..] value=Mission Five>
                      ^----^---attribute + value
                                   ^---new attribute with no value
```

Try

```
Mission [..snip..] value='" . $mission ."'>
                         ^---------------^
```

producing

```
Mission [..snip..] value='Mission Five'>
```

Comment: `[..snip..]` - I should find you a pair of scissors glyph, or pruning sheets ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The value field is missing quotes

```
Mission: <input readonly type='text' name='mission' value=".$mission.">
```

should be more like

```
Mission: <input readonly type='text' name='mission' value='".$mission."'>
```

This assumes that you are echoing this out as a string with PHP and the string is enclosed in double quotes initially ( which is how it appears due to `".$mission."` )